# Gazebo Spawns My Model Really, Really Far Away

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, spawn-model, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to spawn my robots urdf model in gazebo using

```
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file H20_urdf.urdf -urdf -model Robot -z 0.5
```

But it spawns my robot way out in the middle of no where, [here is an image of where it is in gazebo](https://imgur.com/mnRtU).

My console output says that it spawn successfully, but the robot has spawned on its side and not 0.5m above the origin.

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1358537000.298533] [0.000000] waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
spawn status:  SpawnModel: successfully spawned model
root@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace/learning_urdf#
```

Does anyone know why gazebo is spawning my object incorrectly?

Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52752/gazebo-spawns-my-model-really,-really-far-away/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-01-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I think the problem is that the robot intersects with the floor, try increasing the value of z!

---

Originally posted by [Davide Zanin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4003/davide-zanin/) with karma: 16 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0